# Copy list item and add it to the same list by copying their ID using ecma script

Tags: list, client-object-model

I need to Copy a list item which is selected and add it to the same list using ecma script..no workflow and designer is allowed(only client object model). I tried to copy the list items but i havent tried creating new ID for the copied item.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, as if you are copying an item to the same list you will get an ID automatically. So are you sure you mean ID.

Comment: @BinaryJam I havenot done it completely...let me know first how to copy a single item and paste it in the same list